# Newbie Q: Is there a best practice for custom "onChange" propname and callback parameters?

Tags: reactjs

When I write my own custom components, I need to call one of the props supplied by the container to signal a change in the value handled by the component. But instead of an `e` event, I have a `newValue` handy. So I want to call it like this:

```
props.propname(newValue)
```

Now, is there a React convention / best practice for `propname`?

For DOM inputs, the `onChange` prop gets called with an event parameter, typically named `e`. Its as if it gets called like this:

```
props.onChange(e)
```

Should I:

1. Call the prop something other than `onChange` since it takes different parameters than `onChange` events for DOM elements. Something like: `props.onMyComponentChange(newValue)` (or whatever makes sense for the component).
2. Use the same name and call: `props.onChange(newValue)`. Best practice is that the prop is called `onChange`, but it may take different parameters, depending on the component.
3. Create an `e` event somehow and still call `onChange(e)` (I haven't seen this in the wild)

I did a quick check for npm react components and saw a variety of 1. and 2. When writing new custom components, is there an established best practice for what to call such a prop?

Comment: Updated the answer based on re-reading your question... :) Hope it helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of props as no different than variable names... You should be as explicit with them as possible... Whether you're using `classes` or `hooks` under the hood even classes are still functions... Variables are function-scoped so you won't have any conflicts...

However, as your application grows you'll have a whole bunch of `onSubmits` and `handleSubmits` all over the place and will spend a bunch of time trying to figure out which one belongs to which component/container

Comment: Your points about being explicit and aiding maintenance by making it easier to search for the right prop make total sense. So e.g. for a date picker `onDateChange` makes more sense than `onChange` for multiple reasons. I'll go with the `on${someting}Change` approach. Thanks, @SakoBu!